# Best way to position content side by side on larger screens and full width on smaller screens in HTML email with inline styling

Tags: css, html-email

Hi I am constructing some email HTML. There is a maximum width of 600px wide in the outer container table. I have 3 blocks of content and I need to know the best way to have those three blocks of content side by side on screens 600px wide and over (so each block being a third of the width) but on screens below 600px wide have the first block then below it the next two blocks each take up 50% without using media queries?

Can it be done with tables and columns or do I need to consider something else?

**600px wide and above**

```
===========================================
|   block 1   |   block 2   |   block 3   |
===========================================
```

**Below 600px wide**

Block 1 can but doesn't necessarily need to take up full width as long as block 2 and 3 are below it and they each take up 50% of the width.

```
===============
|   block 1   |
===================================
|     block  2    |    block 3    |
===================================
```

I've tried using table cells with min-widths but that didn't work.

**I need to achieve it with inline styling** which I think rules out media queries and it needs to be well supported across all email platforms. Should I just use divs, min-widths and floats or is there a more supported way?

P.S. they can be wrapped in whatever div / table to achieve it so block 2 and 3 can be wrapped in something separate from block 1 etc if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So, we can use media queries, as long as we realise their limitations. You could do them desktop-first (max-width), in which case those mobile email clients that do not support `<style>` blocks (and hence media queries) would get the desktop version (not good - not responsive). That's largely Gmail IMAP, a type of Gmail primarily used by businesses with their own domain name.

Alternatively, we can do it mobile-first (min-width), in which case those desktop email clients that do not support `<style>` blocks would get the mobile version (there are very few of these, and they tend to be very old ISP webmail).

Mobile-first is the least-worst, IMHO, but it can depend on your audience.

So I'm following the 'fluid-hybrid' method so you can look this up for more info elsewhere. Essentially, by creating 3 inline-blocks at the size we want, we can make it stack organically on mobiles. Then for desktops, we use the media query. For Outlook desktop (Windows), it gets its own wrapper (the if mso's), because it has a print-based rendering engine (MS Word) that doesn't support media queries:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      .three-column .column {
      max-width: 200px;
      }
  }
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin:0;padding:0;min-width:100%;">
    <!-- START OUTER WRAPPER -->
    <center id="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;">
        <div style="max-width:600px;">
            <!--[if mso]><table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"><tr><td style="padding:0;"><![endif]-->
            <table align="center" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:16px;margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
            <!-- END OUTER WRAPPER -->
            <tr>
    <td class="three-column" style="padding:0 0px;text-align: center;font-size:0;">
        <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"><tr><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;"><![endif]-->
        <div class="column" style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
            <img width="200" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" style="width:100%;max-width:200px!important" />
        </div>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;"><![endif]-->
        <div class="column" style="width:50%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
            <img width="200" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" style="width:100%;" />
        </div>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;"><![endif]-->
        <div class="column" style="width:50%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
            <img width="200" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" style="width:100%;" />
        </div>
        <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
                    
            <!-- START OUTER WRAPPER -->
            </table>
            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
    <!-- END OUTER WRAPPER -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No I’m sorry I cannot use any classes. It has to be inline.

Comment: Why don't you try it? You might be surprised. I use this technique on a daily basis for the past few years, so I know it works. What you've learned about needing to go inline is largely correct, but it's also flawed because you can in fact still use classes. There are limitations that I've outlined, however.

Comment: Unfortunately the system that is used to allow HTML into the email has no facility to allow anything other than inline css.

Comment: Ok, and have you tried removing the body and head blocks and just copying in the style blocks anyway? Or does the system still strip them? Because style blocks still work even if they ultimately end up in the body.

Comment: Yes the system wont actually allow body / html tags and it strips all classes and makes no attempt to reinterpret the styles. It'll only accept inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Foundation as well - they have good platform when it comes to ordering elements depending on screen sizes, mobile etc.

[Foundation for Emails 2](https://get.foundation/emails.html#:%7E:text=Foundation%20for%20Emails%20is%20the,Transactional%20Emails)

Comment: I’ve used this before but was a while ago. I thought it used classes. Can it do it purely with online styling?

Comment: Sorry meant to say inline stying.

Comment: they also have a [utility](https://get.foundation/emails/inliner.html) you can use to inline it all.

Comment: Also, check out this link if you're concerned about [compatibility](https://get.foundation/emails/docs/compatibility.html)

Comment: It's not suitable unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without media queries in the following way.

We set it up as follows:

```
===================
|   width: 200px   |
========================================
|      width:100%; max-width:400px      |
|  ===================================  |
| |     width:50%    |    width:50%   | |
|  ===================================  |
========================================
```

Outlook needs its own treatment since it doesn't support max-width, float, display changes, and just about everything else that you might need. So it gets it's own tables that should be self-explanatory (and may or may not be able to be simplified).

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;min-width:100%;">
    <!-- START OUTER WRAPPER -->
    <center style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;">
        <div style="max-width:600px;">
            <!--[if mso]><table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"><tr><td style="padding:0;"><![endif]-->
            <table align="center" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:16px;margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
            <!-- END OUTER WRAPPER -->
            <tr>
    <td style="padding:0 0px;text-align: center;font-size:0;">
        <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"><tr><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;"><![endif]-->
        <div style="width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;font-size:16px;">
            <img width="200" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0000" style="width:100%;max-width:200px!important;vertical-align: top;" />
        </div>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td width="400" valign="top" style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;"><![endif]-->
        <div style="width:100%;max-width:400px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;font-size:16px;">
            <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"><tr><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;"><![endif]-->
            <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
                <img width="200" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/00ff00" style="width:100%;vertical-align: top;" />
            </div>
            <!--[if mso]></td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse;"><![endif]-->
            <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
                <img width="200" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000ff" style="width:100%;vertical-align: top;" />
            </div>
            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
        </div>
        <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
                    
            <!-- START OUTER WRAPPER -->
            </table>
            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
    <!-- END OUTER WRAPPER -->
</body>
</html>
```

You could make block 1 left aligned or centered (this shows as centered) based on the outer `<td style="...text-align: center...` style.

Comment: Could also get block 1 to be full width by utilising the 'fab-four' technique https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-fab-four-technique-to-create-responsive-emails-without-media-queries-baf11fdfa848/